# Bash script not running , user issue

Tags: linux, bash, shell

i've created a bash script `batch-create-users.sh` and I want execute it from the terminal, Im on the folder when the script is and I run the command
`./batch-create-users.sh` and I got error

> the file './batch-create-users.sh' is not executable by this user

I entered as sudo -s and give the password but it doesn't help, any idea?

Comment: Is it executable? `chmod a+x batch-create-users.sh`

Comment: You have to make file executable, try with `chmod +x batch-create-users.sh`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give execute privilege to the file before executing.

```
chmod +x batch-create-users.sh
```